# In asp.net-mvc, what is causing my model state errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, post

I am posting a form in an asp.net-mvc page.  Here is my controller action:

```
    public ActionResult UpdateData(MyFormObject entity)
    {
        bool isValid = IsValid(entity);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            var firstError = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).First();
            throw new HttpException(404, firstError.ErrorMessage);
        }
        return Json(BuildResult(entity));
    }
```

Even thought the post passes all of my explicit validation logic, when i check ModelState I see errors.  I am seeing errors in ModelState when any of my properties are empty.  Here is my object:

```
public class MyFormObject 
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public int TestId{ get; set; }
    public int OtherId{ get; set; }
}
```

and I am looking at Model.State and i see errors for any element in my object that is not populated.

If I change this to  (NOTE: the "?")

```
public class MyFormObject 
{
    public int? Id{ get; set; }
    public int? TestId{ get; set; }
    public int? OtherId{ get; set; }
}
```

then i no longer get any errors.  Is there some default validation that is happening here that I am not setting.  I am trying to figure out what is setting ModelState errors in the first case above.

Comment: What does IsValid do? And why not just be explicit with ModelState.IsValid

Comment: Show the view markup as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Maxim V. Pavlov said, when you post, ASP.MVC engine will try to validate the model, ie its class, and based on class you cited as example, the properties don't accepts a null or empty value, then it will throw an exception and ModelState will be invalid.

You can see more here @ [Validating Model Data in an MVC Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410404%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and here [ModelStateDictionary.IsValid Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.isvalid%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

When you are positing to a controller action that takes `MyFormObject` class object as a parameter, MVC engine will try to create an instance of that class via automatic model-binding. In order to create `MyFormObject` one needs to provide all of these:

```
public int Id{ get; set; }
public int TestId{ get; set; }
public int OtherId{ get; set; }
```

and if you don't provide at least any of these, it will try to assign null to the corresponding property. The `int` (value type) doesn't support null values, whereas `int?` does.

This is logically correct and actually helps you in a long run.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably submitting an empty MyFormObject to your UpdateData method. Value-types cannot be null and **must** be assigned a value. If a value is missing for a value-type, then it automatically will trigger a required field validation.

ASP.NET MVC even has a property that allows you to tweak this behaviour, although I believe it will only influence client-side validation:

[DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelvalidatorprovider.addimplicitrequiredattributeforvaluetypes%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Comment: I am not passing in an empty object, just some of the properties are empty . . my point is that shouldn't it be up to be me to determine if that should create a ModelState error ?  I know i could create my own Model validation logic on top of this but trying to understand this default behavior

Comment: The default behavior is to implicitly require fields that are value-type to have a value. What should happen if these properties are empty? Should they default to zero? Should they be 'null'?